# How can I make all the cards in my Bootstrap 5 carousel have the same width and height on all devices

Tags: html, css, visual-studio, frontend, bootstrap-5

I am making a website using Bootstrap 5. I also used it to create a carousel. The cards in the carousel on my PC screen have the same width and height because I use `<br />` to create spaces in the card. But on my phone when I open the site the cards don't have the same width and height. Can you please tell me the proper way to fix this.

### Test.html

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

<title>Home | </title>

<meta name="description" content="Write an awesome description for your new site here. It will appear in your document head meta (for Google search results) and in your feed.xml site description." />

<link rel="stylesheet" href="/_bridgetown/static/css/main.c7d4dd3f1984a290e9be.css" />
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" 
href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.0/css/all.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" 
href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.0/css/all.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/index.css" />
<!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/dropdown.css" /> -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/login-modal.css">
<link
          rel="stylesheet"
          data-purpose="Layout StyleSheet"
          title="Default"
    disabled
          href="/css/app-937c1ff7d52fd6f78dd9322599e2b5d4.css?vsn=d"
        >
        <link
          rel="stylesheet"
          data-purpose="Layout StyleSheet"
          title="Web Awesome"

          href="/css/app-wa-8d95b745961f6b33ab3aa1b98a45291a.css?vsn=d"
        >

          
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link
            rel="stylesheet"

            href="https://site-assets.fontawesome.com/releases/v6.4.0/css/all.css"
          >

          <link
            rel="stylesheet"

            href="https://site-assets.fontawesome.com/releases/v6.4.0/css/sharp-solid.css"
          >

          <link
            rel="stylesheet"

            href="https://site-assets.fontawesome.com/releases/v6.4.0/css/sharp-regular.css"
          >

          <link
            rel="stylesheet"

            href="https://site-assets.fontawesome.com/releases/v6.4.0/css/sharp-light.css"
          >
        <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/images/favicon-32x32.png">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- OUR CLIENTS SECTION START -->
    <section class="bg-dark text-center mb-2">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row text-white py-5">
            <h2 class="display-6">100's of Companies have Switched to Company name</h2>
            <div class="col-12">
              <a 
                
                class="btn btn-primary" 
                href="#carouseldemo1" role="button" 
                data-bs-slide="prev"
              >
                <i class="fa fa-arrow-left"></i>
              </a>
              <a 
  
                class="btn btn-primary" 
                href="#carouseldemo1" role="button" 
                data-bs-slide="next"
              >
                <i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i>
              </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-12">
              <div class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel" id="carouseldemo1">
                <div class="carousel-inner">
                  <div class="carousel-item active">
                    <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-lg-4">
                        <div class="card bg-light text-dark my-3">
                          <img src="./assets/Generic-Profile.png" class="img-fluid rounded-circle mt-4" id="rounded_circle" />
                          <div class="card-body">
                            <p class="lead text-center text-muted mt-4">Shane Gunderson</p>
                            <p>Great work! Thank you for successfully repairing the hardware here and following scope!
                              <br />
                              <br />
  
                            </p>
                            <p class="text-warning">
                              <i class="fa-solid fa-star fa-1x"></i>
                              <i class="fa-solid fa-star fa-1x"></i>
                              <i class="fa-solid fa-star fa-1x"></i>
                              <i class="fa-solid fa-star fa-1x"></i>
                              <i class="fa-solid fa-star fa-1x"></i>
  
                            </p>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-lg-4">
                        <div class="card bg-light text-dark my-3">
                          <img src="./assets/Generic-Profile.png" class="img-fluid rounded-circle mt-4" id="rounded_circle" />
                          <div class="card-body">
                            <p class="lead text-center text-muted mt-4">Mark Otterbeck</p>
                            <p>Company name did a great job of making sure the end user was taken care of. Service was quick and accurate.
  
                            </p>
                            <p class="text-warning">
                              <i class="fa-solid fa-star fa-1x"></i>
                              <i class="fa-solid fa-star fa-1x"></i>
                              <i class="fa-solid fa-star fa-1x"></i>
                              <i class="fa-solid fa-star fa-1x"></i>
                              <i class="fa-solid fa-star fa-1x"></i>
  
                            </p>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-lg-4">
                        <div class="card bg-light text-dark my-3">
                          <img src="./assets/Generic-Profile.jpg" class="img-fluid rounded-circle mt-4" id="rounded_circle" />
                          <div class="card-body">
                            <p class="lead text-center text-muted mt-4">Matt Franklin</p>
                            <p>Did a good job for us.
                              <br />
                              <br />
                              <br />
  
                            </p>
                            <p class="text-warning">
                              <i class="fa-solid fa-star fa-1x"></i>
                              <i class="fa-solid fa-star fa-1x"></i>
                              <i class="fa-solid fa-star fa-1x"></i>
                              <i class="fa-solid fa-star fa-1x"></i>
                              <i class="fa-solid fa-star fa-1x"></i>
  
                            </p>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="carousel-item">
                    <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-lg-4">
                        <div class="card bg-light text-dark my-3">
                          <img src="./assets/Generic-Profile.jpg" class="img-fluid rounded-circle mt-4" id="rounded_circle" />
                          <div class="card-body">
                            <p class="lead text-center text-muted mt-4">Arthur Jenkin</p>
                            <p>Company name ALWAYS does a GREAT job for us. HIGHLY recommend their services. Thank you.
                              <br />
                              <br />
                              <br />
                            </p>
                            <p class="text-warning">
                              <i class="fa-solid fa-star fa-1x"></i>
                              <i class="fa-solid fa-star fa-1x"></i>
                              <i class="fa-solid fa-star fa-1x"></i>
                              <i class="fa-solid fa-star fa-1x"></i>
                              <i class="fa-solid fa-star fa-1x"></i>
  
                            </p>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-lg-4">
                        <div class="card bg-light text-dark my-3">
                          <img src="./assets/Generic-Profile.png" class="img-fluid rounded-circle mt-4" id="rounded_circle" />
                          <div class="card-body">
                            <p class="lead text-center text-muted mt-4">Michele Mulins</p>
                            <p>Site was very unorganized and unprepared. Technician did an excellent job to work around this and provide the best service. We really appreciate the work you've done for these sites!
                              <br />
  
                            </p>
                            <p class="text-warning">
                              <i class="fa-solid fa-star fa-1x"></i>
                              <i class="fa-solid fa-star fa-1x"></i>
                              <i class="fa-solid fa-star fa-1x"></i>
                              <i class="fa-solid fa-star fa-1x"></i>
                              <i class="fa-solid fa-star fa-1x"></i>
  
                            </p>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-lg-4">
                        <div class="card bg-light text-dark my-3">
                          <img src="./assets/Generic-Profile.png" class="img-fluid rounded-circle mt-4" id="rounded_circle" />
                          <div class="card-body">
                            <p class="lead text-center text-muted mt-4">Kathy Bottka</p>
                            <p>Job well done.
                              <br />
                              <br />
                              <br />
                              <br />
  
                            </p>
                            <p class="text-warning">
                              <i class="fa-solid fa-star fa-1x"></i>
                              <i class="fa-solid fa-star fa-1x"></i>
                              <i class="fa-solid fa-star fa-1x"></i>
                              <i class="fa-solid fa-star fa-1x"></i>
                              <i class="fa-solid fa-star fa-1x"></i>
  
                            </p>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
      <!-- OUR CLIENTS SECTION CLOSE -->
    

  </body>
</html>
```

### Test.css

```css
/* @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins&display=swap'); */

body {
    background: hsl(233, 47%, 96%);
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

hr {
    border: 1.5px solid hsl(216, 90%, 44%)
}

.crd {
    background: hsl(233, 47%, 96%);
    transition: all;
}

.crd:hover {
    background: hsl(216, 90%, 44%);
    color: #fff;
    transition: 0.5s;
} 

.card img {
    margin: auto;
    
}

#rounded_circle {
    width: 76px;
    aspect-ratio: 1;
    background-color: hsl(0, 0%, 75%);
}

footer a {
    color: hsl(0, 0%, 100%);
}

#footer {
    color: hsl(0, 0%, 100%);
}

#copyright {
    border-top: 1px solid hsl(0, 0%, 20%) ;
}

.c-item {
    height: 480px;
}

.c-img {
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
    filter: brightness(0.6);
}

#team-img {
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
}

@media (min-width: 576px) {
    .dropdown:hover > .dropdown-menu {
        display: block;
        margin-top: 0;
    }
}

footer li:hover {
    color: hsl(24, 83%, 65%);
    transition: 0.2s;
}

footer i:hover {
    color: hsl(24, 83%, 65%);
    transition: 0.2s;
}

/* #navmenu li{
    background:hsl(0, 0%, 100%);
    transition: all;
}

#navmenu li:hover {
    background: hsl(24, 83%, 65%);
    transition: 0.5s;
} */

#sub-header {
    color: hsl(24, 83%, 65%);
}
```

```css
/* @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins&display=swap'); */

body {
    background: hsl(233, 47%, 96%);
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

hr {
    border: 1.5px solid hsl(216, 90%, 44%)
}

.crd {
    background: hsl(233, 47%, 96%);
    transition: all;
}

.crd:hover {
    background: hsl(216, 90%, 44%);
    color: #fff;
    transition: 0.5s;
} 

.card img {
    margin: auto;
    
}

#rounded_circle {
    width: 76px;
    aspect-ratio: 1;
    background-color: hsl(0, 0%, 75%);
}

footer a {
    color: hsl(0, 0%, 100%);
}

#footer {
    color: hsl(0, 0%, 100%);
}

#copyright {
    border-top: 1px solid hsl(0, 0%, 20%) ;
}

.c-item {
    height: 480px;
}

.c-img {
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
    filter: brightness(0.6);
}

#team-img {
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
}

@media (min-width: 576px) {
    .dropdown:hover > .dropdown-menu {
        display: block;
        margin-top: 0;
    }
}

footer li:hover {
    color: hsl(24, 83%, 65%);
    transition: 0.2s;
}

footer i:hover {
    color: hsl(24, 83%, 65%);
    transition: 0.2s;
}

/* #navmenu li{
    background:hsl(0, 0%, 100%);
    transition: all;
}

#navmenu li:hover {
    background: hsl(24, 83%, 65%);
    transition: 0.5s;
} */

#sub-header {
    color: hsl(24, 83%, 65%);
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

<title>Home | </title>

<meta name="description" content="Write an awesome description for your new site here. It will appear in your document head meta (for Google search results) and in your feed.xml site description." />

<link rel="stylesheet" href="/_bridgetown/static/css/main.c7d4dd3f1984a290e9be.css" />
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" 
href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.0/css/all.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" 
href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.0/css/all.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/index.css" />
<!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/dropdown.css" /> -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/login-modal.css">
<link
          rel="stylesheet"
          data-purpose="Layout StyleSheet"
          title="Default"
    disabled
          href="/css/app-937c1ff7d52fd6f78dd9322599e2b5d4.css?vsn=d"
        >
        <link
          rel="stylesheet"
          data-purpose="Layout StyleSheet"
          title="Web Awesome"

          href="/css/app-wa-8d95b745961f6b33ab3aa1b98a45291a.css?vsn=d"
        >

          
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link
            rel="stylesheet"

            href="https://site-assets.fontawesome.com/releases/v6.4.0/css/all.css"
          >

          <link
            rel="stylesheet"

            href="https://site-assets.fontawesome.com/releases/v6.4.0/css/sharp-solid.css"
          >

          <link
            rel="stylesheet"

            href="https://site-assets.fontawesome.com/releases/v6.4.0/css/sharp-regular.css"
          >

          <link
            rel="stylesheet"

            href="https://site-assets.fontawesome.com/releases/v6.4.0/css/sharp-light.css"
          >
        <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/images/favicon-32x32.png">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- OUR CLIENTS SECTION START -->
    <section class="bg-dark text-center mb-2">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row text-white py-5">
            <h2 class="display-6">100's of Companies have Switched to Company name</h2>
            <div class="col-12">
              <a 
                
                class="btn btn-primary" 
                href="#carouseldemo1" role="button" 
                data-bs-slide="prev"
              >
                <i class="fa fa-arrow-left"></i>
              </a>
              <a 
  
                class="btn btn-primary" 
                href="#carouseldemo1" role="button" 
                data-bs-slide="next"
              >
                <i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i>
              </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-12">
              <div class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel" id="carouseldemo1">
                <div class="carousel-inner">
                  <div class="carousel-item active">
                    <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-lg-4">
                        <div class="card bg-light text-dark my-3">
                          <img src="./assets/Generic-Profile.png" class="img-fluid rounded-circle mt-4" id="rounded_circle" />
                          <div class="card-body">
                            <p class="lead text-center text-muted mt-4">Shane Gunderson</p>
                            <p>Great work! Thank you for successfully repairing the hardware here and following scope!
                              <br />
                              <br />
  
                            </p>
                            <p class="text-warning">
                              <i class="fa-solid fa-star fa-1x"></i>
                              <i class="fa-solid fa-star fa-1x"></i>
                              <i class="fa-solid fa-star fa-1x"></i>
                              <i class="fa-solid fa-star fa-1x"></i>
                              <i class="fa-solid fa-star fa-1x"></i>
  
                            </p>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-lg-4">
                        <div class="card bg-light text-dark my-3">
                          <img src="./assets/Generic-Profile.png" class="img-fluid rounded-circle mt-4" id="rounded_circle" />
                          <div class="card-body">
                            <p class="lead text-center text-muted mt-4">Mark Otterbeck</p>
                            <p>Company name did a great job of making sure the end user was taken care of. Service was quick and accurate.
  
                            </p>
                            <p class="text-warning">
                              <i class="fa-solid fa-star fa-1x"></i>
                              <i class="fa-solid fa-star fa-1x"></i>
                              <i class="fa-solid fa-star fa-1x"></i>
                              <i class="fa-solid fa-star fa-1x"></i>
                              <i class="fa-solid fa-star fa-1x"></i>
  
                            </p>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-lg-4">
                        <div class="card bg-light text-dark my-3">
                          <img src="./assets/Generic-Profile.jpg" class="img-fluid rounded-circle mt-4" id="rounded_circle" />
                          <div class="card-body">
                            <p class="lead text-center text-muted mt-4">Matt Franklin</p>
                            <p>Did a good job for us.
                              <br />
                              <br />
                              <br />
  
                            </p>
                            <p class="text-warning">
                              <i class="fa-solid fa-star fa-1x"></i>
                              <i class="fa-solid fa-star fa-1x"></i>
                              <i class="fa-solid fa-star fa-1x"></i>
                              <i class="fa-solid fa-star fa-1x"></i>
                              <i class="fa-solid fa-star fa-1x"></i>
  
                            </p>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="carousel-item">
                    <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-lg-4">
                        <div class="card bg-light text-dark my-3">
                          <img src="./assets/Generic-Profile.jpg" class="img-fluid rounded-circle mt-4" id="rounded_circle" />
                          <div class="card-body">
                            <p class="lead text-center text-muted mt-4">Arthur Jenkin</p>
                            <p>Company name ALWAYS does a GREAT job for us. HIGHLY recommend their services. Thank you.
                              <br />
                              <br />
                              <br />
                            </p>
                            <p class="text-warning">
                              <i class="fa-solid fa-star fa-1x"></i>
                              <i class="fa-solid fa-star fa-1x"></i>
                              <i class="fa-solid fa-star fa-1x"></i>
                              <i class="fa-solid fa-star fa-1x"></i>
                              <i class="fa-solid fa-star fa-1x"></i>
  
                            </p>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-lg-4">
                        <div class="card bg-light text-dark my-3">
                          <img src="./assets/Generic-Profile.png" class="img-fluid rounded-circle mt-4" id="rounded_circle" />
                          <div class="card-body">
                            <p class="lead text-center text-muted mt-4">Michele Mulins</p>
                            <p>Site was very unorganized and unprepared. Technician did an excellent job to work around this and provide the best service. We really appreciate the work you've done for these sites!
                              <br />
  
                            </p>
                            <p class="text-warning">
                              <i class="fa-solid fa-star fa-1x"></i>
                              <i class="fa-solid fa-star fa-1x"></i>
                              <i class="fa-solid fa-star fa-1x"></i>
                              <i class="fa-solid fa-star fa-1x"></i>
                              <i class="fa-solid fa-star fa-1x"></i>
  
                            </p>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-lg-4">
                        <div class="card bg-light text-dark my-3">
                          <img src="./assets/Generic-Profile.png" class="img-fluid rounded-circle mt-4" id="rounded_circle" />
                          <div class="card-body">
                            <p class="lead text-center text-muted mt-4">Kathy Bottka</p>
                            <p>Job well done.
                              <br />
                              <br />
                              <br />
                              <br />
  
                            </p>
                            <p class="text-warning">
                              <i class="fa-solid fa-star fa-1x"></i>
                              <i class="fa-solid fa-star fa-1x"></i>
                              <i class="fa-solid fa-star fa-1x"></i>
                              <i class="fa-solid fa-star fa-1x"></i>
                              <i class="fa-solid fa-star fa-1x"></i>
  
                            </p>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
      <!-- OUR CLIENTS SECTION CLOSE -->
    

  </body>
</html>
```